# I am trying to create an effect that when I hover into a div it would then effect all the children

Tags: html, css, hover, children

I'm really new to HTML and CSS, I've been picking it up along the way as I've been creating my website. It's been going pretty well up until my portfolio page, what my problem is I've created a portfolio home page which shows all of my work with a title and a short description of the project, I have styled the CSS to change the image on hover to light up (using a spite sheet and moving the position of the image) and the title to turn blue as well as the description, my problem is that I want all of these elements or children of the section to activate at the same time when the mouse is hovered into the section, at the moment the hover effect only works when you hover over each child.

I have looked for ages for a solution but can't seem to find any, I would really appreciate some help with this problem, it is probably a really simple fix but I'm very new to web development so I'm stuck!

Here is my HTML for the section

```
`<section id="port1">
<a href="tempura.html">
<div id="image1"></div>
<h3>TEMPURA</h3>
<p>Branding project incorporating the japanese culture and an animal as the key elements to       represent the brand.</p>
</a>
</section>`
```

and here is the CSS

```
`#port1 {
width:247px;
height:280px;
float:left;
background-color:#FFF;
text-decoration:none;

}

#port1 a {
text-decoration:none;

}

#image1 {
height:150px;
width:227px;
background-image:url(../images/Tempuraimg.jpg);
background-position:top left;
margin:10px;
float:left;

}

#image1:hover {
background-position:bottom left;

}

#port1 h3 {
font-size:10pt; 
font-family:"Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
color:#333;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
padding-bottom:5px;
padding-top:5px;
border-bottom:1px dotted #999;
text-decoration:none;

}

#port1 h3:hover {
color:#09F;

}

#port1 p {
font-size:8pt;  
font-family:"Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:200;
color:#999;
padding-top:10px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
text-decoration:none;

}

#port1 p:hover {
color:#0099FF;

}`
```

Finally this is my website so far and the page is question is the portfolio page here is the link

http://mattwilsongraphicdesigns.co.uk/portfolio.html

If you think you can help me out I'd be very grateful

Best wishes

Matt Wilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give **:hover** to the parent & change his `child's` style according to them. Write like this:

```
#port1:hover p,
#port1:hover h3{
 color:#0099FF;
}

#port1:hover #image1{
 background-position:bottom left;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! that has worked! I've been looking for an answer for this for about a week now! thanks a lot man!

Comment: sandeep's method will work but you should know that the way you coded your HTML and CSS is inefficient. If you used classes your CSS file will be 6 times smaller.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy first the code is not inefficient. Second i am not coded anything. I am only show a way to achieve the desire effect

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is not the best way to be honest as you're using too much IDs. You could simply use classes instead of IDs ... Instead of port1, port2, port3 ... and rewriting the same rules over and over you could simply use class="port". CSS is about the amount of work and effort by writing reusable rules that could be used over and over again.

You should read more about CSS. I would recommend you check [CSS Beginner Tutorials on HTML Dog](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/)

Any way this is how to achieve what's you want to do. This will work across all browsers except IE6 as it doesn't recognize :hover except on anchor elements

```
#wrapper section:hover p,
#wrapper section:hover h3 {
    color:#0099FF;
}

#wrapper #image1{
    background-position:bottom left;
}
```

Or you could use this selector for the image container to be used once instead of #image1, #image2 ... etc

```
div[id^=image] {
    background-position:bottom left;
}
```

Comment: So how would you suggest I do this? as I want the images to light up too?

Comment: oh okay I think I see what you mean I will have to look into that in future as I'm still new to Coding so I don't really know the most effective ways to work! Thanks a lot man!